# Why extension manager is not showing installed extensions in vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've installed several extensions in my vs 2010. All have been installed in Extension Manager but not showing in Tools-Options-Extension Manager.

Like I've installed web essentials and I want to change settings of this extension but it's not appearing in Tools-Options-Extension Manager.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do?

Comment: This question has **nothing** to do with extension methods, please stop adding that tag to the post.

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Extesions is not where you go to see installed extensions, it's where you go to configure how extensions are managed. I no longer have access to Visual Studio 2010 but under the Tools menu there should be an option like "Extensions" or "Manage Extensions". That's where you'll find your installed extensions. However, that's not where you go to configure the extensions anyway. Each extension would be listed somewhere in the Tools -> Options dialog and that's where you configure them.

Comment: @Craig, I can see the web essentials in extension manager as you can see in the image but when I'm trying to find it in project or solution by right clicking it there is no option for web essentials.

Answer (score 0):

Web essentials provide setting per solution basis. Right click your solution and click on web essentials.It will create a xml file where you can set your preferences.

Go through this article- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/11/05/making-web-development-wonderful-again-with-web-essentials.aspx and see solution setting part.

There is another option also. Goto Tools-> Options-> Web Essentials from visual Studio.

Comment: Actually web essentials option is not coming in Right click of solution.

Comment: I edited answer also. You can try tools-> Options-> Web Essentials